# How to adjust center axis width in a butterfly chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a butterfly chart. I create a center zero axis with "Text" type. Everything goes fine, except for one thing.

The width of the center axis is too broad, I want to change the width. But I don't know how to do it.

If I shrink the center axis, left and right are also shrunk. It seems the ratio of width is fixed.

[image]

Here is my [demo workbook](https://public.tableau.com/views/ButterflyChartDemo/butterflychart?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes&:origin=viz_share_link) on Tableau Public.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your butterfly chart following the steps below.
[image: Your Butterfly Chart]

"Concatenated by Dashboard

To shrink the middle margin, we can use a dashboard to concatenate instead of a single worksheet.

1. Divide into three Worksheets: right-click on the sheet tab and duplicate three copies. Remove the other parts in each worksheet.
2. Create a Dashboard and concatenate three segments: drag these segments to the corresponding positions.
3. Change the Dashboard Size to 1200 x 4500. concatenated by dashboard
4. Set left and right segments as Standard and set the middle segment as Fit Width. Then, Resize them to a proper layout.
5. Right-click Legends and check Floating, then put them in the appropriate place.
6. Polish the chart:
   Keep only the left title and remove others.
   show and rename the left and right axis."

Source: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/tableau-playbook-diverging-bar-chart

Comment: haha, actually the source which you refer to is written by me. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I just saw your username there lol. I'm glad you were able to figure it out!